# Showing posts by current user - Meteor

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to show posts by the current logged in user. I tried the same method which I used for showing comments under related post's page but doesn't work for logged in user's posts.

```
Template.myPosts.helpers({
    posts: function () {
        selector = {userId: this.userId};
        options = {sort: {createdAt: -1}};
        return Posts.find(selector, options);
    }
});
```

I also tried the code below in router.js (iron router package installed):

```
this.route('myPosts', {
        path:'/my-posts',
            data:function(){
                return Posts.find({userId: this.userId})
        }             
                            });
})
```

If the code above is not close to how it should be, any hints on how to proceed will be well appreciated. This is a project for only learning purposes.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Meteor, how can I query only the records of a given subscription?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27748100/in-meteor-how-can-i-query-only-the-records-of-a-given-subscription)

Comment: Do you have the subscribe and publish code too?

Comment: @k.chao.0424 I tried that as well. I've been trying different methods with different (famous) packages for the last 4-5 hours and still failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the context of your helper has a `userId` property? Maybe you want this:

```js
Template.myPosts.helpers({
  posts: function () {
    selector = {userId: Meteor.userId()};
    options = {sort: {createdAt: -1}};
    return Posts.find(selector, options);
  }
});
```

It's also worth trying: `Posts.find({userId: Meteor.userId()}).fetch()` in the web console to see if you have any such posts actually published to the client.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have this for userId property: Template.secret.helpers({
  isOwner: function () {
    return this.owner === Meteor.userId();
  }

Comment: And this inside Posts.insert " owner: Meteor.userId(), ". Should I use "owner" instead of userId?

Comment: HOLY SNAP! It worked! What a stupid mistake... It took my 4-5 hours... Thank you very much again for your help David! You answered all my questions until now. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a problem with your publications and subscriptions. Make sure you have publish and subscribe properly.

On `/server/publications.js`:

```
Meteor.publish("postsPub", function (selector, options) {
  return Posts.find(selector, options);
});
```

On your router:

```
this.route('myPosts', {
  path:'/my-posts',
    waitOn : function () {
      selector = {userId: Meteor.userId()};
      options = {sort: {createdAt: -1}};
      return Meteor.subscribe('postsPub', selector, options);
    },
    data:function(){
      return Posts.find({userId: Meteor.userId()});
    }
});
```

Comment: Autopublish and insecure are both removed. Is it possible to do this without installing them back? I've been trying for the last 4-5 hours... Yes. 4-5 hours... HALP!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately returns an empty page. Tried changing "Meteor.userId()" with this.userId (which is used in different places). Trying a few other things now.